# Hi everyone i need you guys to help me optimize my code

Tags: python-3.x

in my current situation the i'm iterating over a json message and then saving the results in a list and then again comparing the items of the list with the json message and then saving the result in a dictionary.
so can this process be more optimized by saving the data directly in 2D-array or dictionary

i'm getting the expected result but i want it to be in amore optimized method

```
result = res.json()
vid_count_db = len(result['hits']['hits'])
print(vid_count_db) 
sensor_id = ''
listsi=[]
dict = {}


for x in result['hits']['hits']:
    sensor_id = x["_source"]["sensor"]
    listsi.append(sensor_id) 

for y in listsi:
    count = 0

for z in result['hits']['hits']:
    if y == z['_source']['sensor']:
        count = count+1
    dict[y]=count
print(dict)
```

Comment: What do you expect `y` to be in the last loop? Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Probably you should be using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). But the code you have shown in your question doesn't make much sense; e.g. you have a loop which does nothing except set `count` to zero many times.